# How does the kernel scheduler know a timeslice has passed?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, process, scheduling, interrupt

In my previous question [How does the kernel scheduler know how to pre-empt a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457502/how-does-the-kernel-scheduler-know-how-to-pre-empt-a-process) I was given an answer to how pre-emption occurs.

Now I am wondering, how does the kernel scheduler know that a timeslice has passed? I read up on the hardware timer solution which makes sense to me, but then I read that most current operating systems (e.g. Windows, Linux, etc.) do *not* use hardware timers, but rather software timers.

How can software timers be used to pre-empt a process once it has taken up its timeslice (e.g. it did not pre-empt itself.) It seems like some hardware timer would be necessary?

Comment: There is a hardware timer interrupt that provides the basic heartbeat. All sorts of other facilities are built on top of that, but you need a hardware timer. See e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481032/where-is-hardware-timer-interrupt .

Comment: `man 7 time` - https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-time/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like some hardware timer would be necessary?

Yes, the kernel relies on hardware to generate an interrupt at regular intervals. On PCs, this was historically the [8253/8254 programmable interval timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8253), or an emulation thereof, then the [local APIC timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller), then the [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer).

Current Linux kernels can be built to run “tickless” when possible: the kernel will program timers to only fire when necessary, and if a given CPU is running a single process, that may well be “never”. In most cases, dynamic ticks are used, so the kernel sets timers up to fire at varying intervals depending on its requirements — fewer interrupts means fewer wake-ups, which means idle CPUs can be kept in low-power modes for longer periods, which saves energy.